# PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED inside Singleton

Tags: jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, entitymanager

We are using Jboss 7.1.1 in an application mostly generated by Jboss Forge, however we added a repository layer for all domain related code.

I was trying to create a Startup bean to initialize the database state. I would like to use my existing repositories for that.

My repositories all have an extended PersistenceContext injected into them. I use these from my View beans that are @ConversationScoped @Stateful beans, by using the extended context my entities remain managed during a conversation.

First I tried this:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ConfigBean {

    @Inject
    private StatusRepository statusRepository;

    @Inject
    private ZipCode zipCodeRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createData() {
        statusRepository.add(new Status("NEW"));
        zipCodeRepository.add(new ZipCode("82738"));
    }

}

Example repository:
@Stateful
public class ZipCodeRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManger em;

    public void add(ZipCode zipCode) {
        em.persist(zipCode);
    }

    ....
}
```

This ends up throwing an javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException on Application startup with the following message:

> JBAS011437: Found extended persistence context in SFSB invocation call stack but that cannot be used because the transaction already has a transactional context associated with it.  This can be avoided by changing application code, either eliminate the extended persistence context or the transactional context.  See JPA spec 2.0 section 7.6.3.1.

I struggled finding a good explanation for this, and actually figured that since EJB's and their injection are handled by proxies all the PersistenceContext injection and propagation would be handled automatically. I guess I was wrong.

However, while on this trail of thought I tried the following:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ConfigBean {

    @Inject
    private SetupBean setupBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createData() {
        setupBean.createData();
    }

    @Stateful
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public static class SetupBean {

        @Inject
        private StatusRepository statusRepository;

        @Inject
        private ZipCode zipCodeRepository;

        public void createData() {
            statusRepository.add(new Status("NEW"));
            zipCodeRepository.add(new ZipCode("82738"));
        }
    }
}
```

This does the trick. All I did was wrap the code in a Stateful SessionBean that is a static inner class of my Singleton bean.

Does anyone understand this behavior? Because while everything works now I'm still a bit estranged as to why it works this way.

Answer (score 3):

> - A container-managed extended persistence context can only be initiated
>     within the scope of a stateful session bean. It exists from the point
>     at which the stateful session bean that declares a dependency on an
>     entity manager of type PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED is created, and
>     is said to be bound to the stateful session bean.

From the posted code, it seems `ZipCodeRepository` isn't itself stateful bean, but you're calling it from one such bean.

In this case, you are initiating `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION` from `ConfigBean`  & propogates through `ZipCodeRepository` having `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` & it tries to join the transaction, hence the exception.

> - Invocation of an entity manager defined with PersistenceContext- Type.EXTENDED will result in the use of the existing extended
>     persistence context bound to that component.
> - When a business method of the stateful session bean is invoked, if the stateful session bean uses container managed transaction
>     demarcation, and the entity manager is not already associated with the
>     current JTA transaction, the container associates the entity manager
>     with the current JTA transaction and calls
>     EntityManager.joinTransaction. If there is a different persistence
>     context already associated with the JTA transaction, the container
>     throws the EJBException.

While in later case, you're creating a new transaction in `SetupBean` for each invocation with `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` which is of extended type, as it's a stateful bean.

Therefore, adding `SetupBean` as stateful session bean initiating new transaction for each invocation & later calling `ZipCodeRepository` doesn't result in exception. `ZipCodeRepository` will join the same transaction as initiated by `SetupBean`.

Comment: I changed my original post to reflect that our repositories are infact stateful sessionbeans. Other than that (which was my mistake) your explanation makes sense :)